# Two similar factory classes to instantiate services

Tags: java, generics, factory-method

I'm working on building a library to help you bootstrap the development of a [Java API](https://github.com/rsparkyc/apibuilder/tree/b8d04a6506dba784bbbf6a8a2a09ce88b96bbbb5). The premise is, you can have your controllers implement interfaces like `IGetController<SomeEntity>` or `IListController<SomeEntity>`.  These interfaces have `default` methods to implement their endpoint, and use a service factory to get the appropriate service to do the bulk of the work.  These services are also interfaces, and have `default` methods which get a repository (by calling `getRepository` on the `IBaseService` they extend).  There's a lot of "magic" going on here to inspect the `genericInterfaces` on the class, and then getting the type arguments to determine what entity we're working with.

The problem I'm having is consolidating my factories.  Take a look at these two factory classes:

`GetServiceFactory`:

```
package apibuilder.service.factory;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import apibuilder.entity.BaseEntity;
import apibuilder.service.IGetService;

public class GetServiceFactory {
    private static final Map<Type, IGetService<? extends BaseEntity>>
            registrationMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T extends BaseEntity> IGetService<T> getService(final Type entityType) {
        if (registrationMap.containsKey(entityType)) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (IGetService<T>) registrationMap.get(entityType);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T extends BaseEntity> void registerServices(final IGetService<T>[] services) {
        for (IGetService<T> service : services) {
            Type entityType = ((ParameterizedType) service.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0])
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            registrationMap.put(entityType, service);
        }
    }
}
```

`ListServiceFactory`:

```
package apibuilder.service.factory;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import apibuilder.entity.BaseEntity;
import apibuilder.service.IListService;

public class ListServiceFactory {
    private static final Map<Type, IListService<? extends BaseEntity>>
            registrationMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static <T extends BaseEntity> IListService<T> getService(final Type entityType) {
        if (registrationMap.containsKey(entityType)) {
            //noinspection unchecked
            return (IListService<T>) registrationMap.get(entityType);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static <T extends BaseEntity> void registerServices(final IListService<T>[] services) {
        for (IListService<T> service : services) {
            Type entityType = ((ParameterizedType) service.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0])
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            registrationMap.put(entityType, service);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, they're nearly identical.  They create a map to get the proper service per entity, and then have methods to build the map, and get a service from the map.  I feel like these can be consolidated into some sort of `BaseServiceFactory`, but I'm having a hard time actually pulling it off.

Comment: I actually ended up abandoning this project once I discovered spring-data-rest, which accomplishes what I was trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that you prefer *static* methods. This way you effectively throw away benefits of *polymorphism*.

Also, when ever you find duplicated code you should carefully think if it might belong into a class of its own.

If you could open your mint to an OO approach you could move common behavior into a (non static) *utility class* and inject that common behavior into the concrete Factories. Or you go the *usual* OO way to create an *abstract* factory having the common code and have the concrete factories inheriting from it.

---

> but *why* do static methods throw away polymorphism benefits?  – Thufir

Static method imply *early binding*. All accessors to a method are known at compile time of the method implementation. Also all implementors of a static method are known at compile time of the accessors. You cannot provide a new behavior of a method unless you compile the accessors needing this new behavior.

```
class A {
  static void method(){
     System.out.println("static method in A");
  }
}


class B extends A {
  static void method(){
     System.out.println("static method B");
  }
}

class  C {
  static void main(String[] args){
     A.method(); // outputs "static method in A"
     B.method(); // outputs "static method in B"
     A[] a = {new A(), new B()};
     a[0].method();  // outputs "static method in A"
     a[1].method();  // outputs "static method in A" although instance is f type `B` 
  }
}
```

> And, is polymorphism really so beneficial? – Thufir

Polymorphism is no value as such.

But if you doubt the value of polymorphism in general you might rather use a programing language that does not bother you with such  gratuitous  concepts...

Comment: but *why* do static methods throw away polymorphism benefits?  (And, is polymorphism really so beneficial?)

Answer (score 0):

Actually that what you have implemented is a Registry not a Factory, so probably you should remove Factory from the class name and use registry.

You could do the following to generalize the class (I am reusing your code):

```
package apibuilder.service.factory;

import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import apibuilder.service.Service;

public class ServiceRegistry {
    private static final Map<Type, Service> registrationMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static Service getService(final Type entityType) {
        if (registrationMap.containsKey(entityType)) {
            return registrationMap.get(entityType);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void registerServices(final Service[] services) {
        for (Service service : services) {
            Type entityType = ((ParameterizedType) service.getClass().getGenericInterfaces()[0])
                    .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
            registrationMap.put(entityType, service);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could define the following interface:

```
public interface Service {

}
```

It will serve as a marker interface and just declare all of your other interfaces as follow (IGetService for example):

```
public interface IGetService<T extends BaseEntity> extends Service {

   ... whatever methods you have ...

}
```

Comment: Ok, won't i be running into issues where my ServiceRegistry's registrationMap is trying to put multiple services in for the same entity type (since entity X could have a create service and an update service)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you will encounter it. What I think you should do is to create a method which will allow registration only of a single service for a given key and as a key you should create your own key which should be a composition of entity and service type and then retrieve the service by this key. If you don't know how to implement proper map key, just search for it